# Errors in sorting a dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, tuples, key-value

This is my code to find and print values of students with the second-lowest score in the given data

```
room =dict()
for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    room.update({name:score})

lowest= min(room.values())
second_lowest = None
for k,v in sorted(room.items(),reverse=True):
    if v == lowest: continue
    elif second_lowest is None:
        second_lowest = v
    elif v < second_lowest:
        second_lowest = v
    if second_lowest==v and second_lowest is not lowest:
        print('name',k)
```

When given a specific set of inputs it returns more than two second_lowest key, for example, for the below input it returns harsh harry and berry where it shouldn't have returned harsh. But this problem disappears if I create a separate `(key, value)` loop with the same

```
sorted(room.items(),reverse=True)
```

**Sample Input:**

```
5 
Harry
37.21
Berry
37.21
Tina
37.2
Akriti
41
Harsh
39
```

**Sample Output:**

```
name Harsh
name Harry
name Berry
```

Comment: The `print` shouldn't be inside the loop: you cannot possibly know what the second-lowest score is at that point, as you haven't seen all the scores yet.  Only after the loop has completed do you have a specific answer to be printed.

Comment: For learning I would recommend using this IDE https://thonny.org/ This allows you to see each variable visually. First try to dry run the code on paper and then compare it with result of each iteration of for loop in thonny and then try to figure out where your logic went wrong.

Comment: What if there are two lowest scores, like 1 and 1?

Comment: It is customary to accept one provided answer, or address deficiencies in the provided answers in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do to find the second lowest scored student:

```
lst = [val for val in room.values() if val != min(list(room.values()))]
for name in room.keys():
    if room[name] == min(lst):
        print('name',name)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  Sort the set (i.e. all the unique values) of scores, and then find the second lowest.  Return the names of students with that score:

```
def return_lowest(scores_dict, n_most=2):
    unique_scores = sorted(list(set(scores_dict.values())))
    score_lowest = unique_scores[n_most-1]
    output = [name for name in scores_dict if scores_dict[name] == score_lowest]
    return output

In[1]: return_lowest({'Bill':100,'Sally':95,'Fred':75,'Gina':75,'Frank':65})
Out[1]:
['Fred', 'Gina']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
second_lowest = sorted(list(set(room.values())))[1]
names = [x for x in room if room[x]==second_lowest]
for name in names:
    print(f"name {name}")
```

**Explanation**

`[x for x in room]` loops over the keys of the `room` dict.

`set(room.values())` will make the scores unique.

`sorted(list(set(room.values())))[1]` will give you the second lowest score.

When put together in a list comprehension will give you the second lowest names.

Comment: This won't work if there are multiple scores that equal to the lowest score. Try this: ``room = {'a':2,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5}``

Comment: That's true. i'll  fix my answer!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest sorting by the score and printing the name of the second element of the sorted array.

```py
room =dict()
for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    room.update({name:score})

second_lowest = sorted(room.values())[1]
print('\n'.join('name: '+ result[0] for result in room.items() 
                if result[1] == second_lowest))
```